# Polynomial $P(x)$ has $n$ real roots in the interval $[a,b]$. Show that the $(n-1)^{st}$ derivative has at least one root in the interval $[a,b]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, polynomials

Assume that $P(x)$ has exactly $n$ roots in the interval $[a,b]$.

How to prove that the $P^{(n-1)}(x)$ polynomial has exactly one derivative in the interval $[a,b]$.

I know that the Rolle's theorem tells us that the first derivative of $P(x)$ has a root in the interval $[a,b]$. How do I go on to prove that the successive derivatives have roots and finally that the $(n-1)^{st}$ derivative has at least one root in the interval?

Comment: and what have you done up to now?

Comment: I know that the Rolle's theorem tells that the derivative of the function has a root in the interval [a,b], but how do I go on after that?
How do I prove that $P^{''}$ has a root and then go on to prove $P^{n-1}$ has only one root?

Comment: So you might just add those things in the question for not getting flagged!

Comment: The title and the question body ask different things ("at least one" vs "exactly one").

Comment: What does `exactly one derivative...` means?

Comment: Not exactly one derivative, but the $(n-1)^{st}$ derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be the roots of $P$, the Rolle theorem implies that there exists a root of $P'$ between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$, so $P'$ has $n-1$ distinct roots continue recursively.

Comment: The question is more precise : you just proved there is **at least** one root for $P^{(n-1)}$, remains to be proved there is **at most** one root.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually false. Let $a = -1$, $b=1$, and $P(x) = (x^2-1)(2x^2 + 1) = 2x^4 - x^2 -1$. $P$ has exactly two roots in $[a,b]$, but $P'(x) = 8x^3 -2x = 8x(x-1/2)(x+1/2)$ has three roots in $[a,b]$

Comment: i think he means that there are only real roots. Otherwise you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Since polynomial’s differential(s) always exists, we can use the “Mean Value Theorem”:

For continuous differentiable function $f(x)$ in $(a,b)$, there exist at least one $c$ where $a < c < b$ such that $f’(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$

Now let us say that $P(x)$ has $n$ distinct real roots in $(a,b)$ which are $d_{1,1},d_{1,2},...,d_{1,n}$

Mean value theorem tells us that there will be:

$d_{1,1} < d_{2,1} < d_{1,2}$ such that $P’(d_{2,1})=\frac{P(d_{1,2})-P(d_{1,1})}{d_{1,2}-d_{1,1}}=0$

$d_{1,2} < d_{2,2} < d_{1,3}$ such that $P’(d_{2,2})=\frac{P(d_{1,3})-P(d_{1,2})}{d_{1,3}-d_{1,2}}=0$

...

$d_{1,n-1} < d_{2,n-1} < d_{1,n}$ such that $P’(d_{2,n-1})=\frac{P(d_{1,n})-P(d_{1,n-1})}{d_{1,n}-d_{1,n-1}}=0$

Therefore, $P’(x)$ has $n-1$ distinct real roots in $(a,b)$ which are $d_{2,1},d_{2,2},...,d_{2,n-1}$.

Repeating, we found $P^{[2]}(x)$ has $n-2$ distinct real roots in $(a,b)$, $P^{[3]}(x)$ has $n-3$, $P^{[4]}(x)$ has $n-4$, and so on.

Notice the pattern?

$P^{[k]}(x)$ has $n-k$ distinct real roots in $(a,b)$.